# Is it possible: TFTP in u-boot to load root filesystem to SD card? (I don't want NFS)

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I know we can use NFS, but I just don't want to use it.

(don't want to keep network connection to NFS server all the time).

- I know we can use tftp in u-boot to load kernel and device-tree!
- But can we use tftp in u-boot to download root-filesystem, put it in the right partition of SD card, and boot?
- If yes, how to do it? (I googled, but found no answers)

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: I'm pretty sure that u-boot's tftp command only reads into RAM - you could then write it to storage with other u-boot commands.  You'd have to have enough RAM to hold the whole thing, and you'd have to know an appropriate RAM address to use, and the appropriate place on your storage device to write to - none of this can be answered generically.

Comment: isn't the idea of "TFTP to load root filesystem" also useful during the developing stage? I thought it should have been realized already.

Comment: Problem is stated too vaguely, i.e. what file format (image, tar) is the rfs?  U-Boot can be configured to have file write capability for ext4 filesystems, or write sectors to the mmc device. But there's no tar extraction. You could always extend U-Boot functionality with a "[standalone application](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootStandalone)" (which could itself be downloaded using TFTP).

Comment: The specific file format is irrelevant: whichever format works, I will use that format! Basically I prefer to "load everything over network", instead of plug/unplug SD-card reader. This is my key-point!

Comment: Then create an image of an ext4 fs, and write it using the mmc commands.  But for testing a kernel I prefer to use an initramfs: it's appended to the kernel, so the kernel + initramfs is downloaded to the target as one image.

Comment: Thanks sawdust, follow your instructions: TFTP loads rootfs to RAM, "mmc write" to rootfs partition, and boot successfully! So the only limit is: rootfs image size can NOT be larger than RAM size.

Comment: *"rootfs image size can NOT be larger than RAM size"* -- No, just the transfer size is limited.  The rootfs image can be [`split`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split) into smaller pieces, and reassembled by writing with the proper offsets.

Comment: Oh really, great to know that, will try "split" later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I use TFTP in uboot to flash my rootfs (for debug purposes) on my internal eMMC. It's nearly the same case as you.

First download in you RAM the filesystem:

```
tftpboot ${rootfs_addr} ${tftppath}/${rootfs_file}
```

- `rootfs_addr` will be the RAM address, I use 0x10800000.
- `tftppath` is the TFTP path (depends on your configuration)
- `rootfs_file` is the ext4 or ext3 file

Then update the mmc device (you can run `mmc list`to show SD u-boot number)

```
mmc dev 2
```

Here I set the device to the number 2, you need to set it corresponding to the `mmc list` command.

Then write the content of the RAM to the SD:

```
setexpr rootfsblksz ${filesize} / 200 
setexpr rootfsblksz ${rootfsblksz} + 1 
mmc write ${rootfs_addr} 6000 ${rootfsblksz}
```

Description:

- I create a `rootfsblksz` variable, it converts the number of bytes downloaded to a number of blocks. `filesize`is set automatically when we use TFTP, it represents the size of the last downloaded file (in Bytes). 
  Here my block is 512Bytes (0x200)
- I add +1 to the blocksize (to be shure to have all the data)
- I write it on the eMMC (or SD) at the address 0x6000 (in blocks) -> 24 576 blocks -> 12 582 912 (in Bytes) -> 12MB because my ext partition is at 12MB offset

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your detailed instructions, it works awesome!